# Is there a way to send an attachment and other cart-level text via cXML Punchout Order Message?

Tags: integration, cxml, coupa

We are a supplier working on cXML Punchout integration with our customers (aka buyers). Our customer is asking for estimated delivery date and a URL/PDF to be sent back to their Procurement system along with the cart.

We tried to add the following to within  but nothing is showing up on customer side (Coupa).

`<Comments> Estimated delivery date: $estDeliveryDate <Attachment> <URL>$URL</URL> </Attachment> </Comments>`